# LibCurl SFTP Rename file

Tags: libcurl, rename, sftp

SOLVED ...

After more shifting around, by using the "rename" as quoted command, it required the full path inclusive of the original name and full path inclusive of rename-to destination.  I didn't try with the path in my other frustrated attempts.

---

Hi all, I've tried all different combinations, keep failing and don't know what I'm missing.  I'm trying to do a simple file rename on a SFTP site using Libcurl.  I've looked all over for answers, but keep coming up short.

BTW... For this testing, there is only one file name in the folder, so no issue about existing file overwrites...  And I'm the login user who originally uploaded the file for any possible "permissions" issues.

My first test was to get the what would be expected as simple syntax correct, but resulted otherwise.  I started with a NON-SFTP site first... just regular FTP.

```
// ex: fpt://mysite.com/subpathNeeded/
curl_easy_setopt(MyCurl, CURLOPT_URL, RemotePath );  


// need a "QUOTE" command before rename will occur in postQuote
strcpy_s( NewCmd, _countof(NewCmd), "PWD \0" );  
quotelist = curl_slist_append(quotelist, NewCmd ); 

// NOW, we can issue the rename from and rename to commands
strcpy_s( RenameFrom, _countof(RenameFrom), "RNFR " );
strcat_s( RenameFrom, _countof(RenameFrom), RemoteCurrentFileName );
postquotelist = curl_slist_append( postquotelist, RenameFrom );

strcpy_s( RenameTo, _countof(RenameTo), "RNTO " );
strcat_s( RenameTo, _countof(RenameTo), RemoteRenameToName );
postquotelist = curl_slist_append( postquotelist, RenameTo );

curl_easy_setopt(MyCurl, CURLOPT_QUOTE, quotelist ); 
curl_easy_setopt(MyCurl, CURLOPT_POSTQUOTE, postquotelist ); 

// NOW, perform the print working directory, then rename...
MyCurlResult = curl_easy_perform(MyCurl);
```

This works no problem. So now, I switch over to SFTP and it fails...  By researching, SFTP doesn't like "PWD", but does allow "pwd" (case issue), no problem.  Then, it doesn't like the RNFR and RNTO but does accept "mv" (move).  So, if I'm in SFTP mode, I change to

```
// lower case "pwd" print working directory
strcpy_s( NewCmd, _countof(NewCmd), "pwd\0" );
quotelist = curl_slist_append(quotelist, NewCmd ); 

// "mv" = move "originalfile" "newfile"
strcpy_s( RenameFrom, _countof(RenameFrom), "mv \"\0" );
strcat_s( RenameFrom, _countof(RenameFrom), RemoteCurrentFileName );
strcat_s( RenameFrom, _countof(RenameFrom), "\" \"\0" );
strcat_s( RenameFrom, _countof(RenameFrom), RemoteRenameToName );
strcat_s( RenameFrom, _countof(RenameFrom), "\"\0" );
postquotelist = curl_slist_append( postquotelist, RenameFrom );
```

I then get a CURL ERROR when I perform this...

However, if I don't try the "mv" command and only send the QUOTE command of "pwd", it goes through fine and it does properly list the expected folder/subdirectory I'm trying to rename the file in.  So I know its in the proper directory.  The values I have in the "RemoteCurrentFileName" and "RemoteRenameToName" are just the stems of the file, no full path to them respectively.  I've also tried including the full path as well and both versions fail.  Ex:

```
RemoteCurrentFileName = "FileIWantToRename.txt"
    or 
RemoteCurrentFileName = "/subpathNeeded/FileIWantToRename.txt"
```

Additionally, I've looked at the documentation and noted "rename" is a valid "QUOTE" command and tried that too..

```
rename "original file" "new file"
```

and that failed too

This should not be this difficult to do.  What simple/stupid am I missing... This is totally frustrating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED ...

After more shifting around, by using the "rename" as quoted command, it required the full path inclusive of the original name and full path inclusive of rename-to destination. I didn't try with the path in my other frustrated attempts

```
strcpy_s( RenameFrom, _countof(RenameFrom), "rename \"\0" );
strcat_s( RenameFrom, _countof(RenameFrom), RemoteCurrentFileNameWithFullPath );
strcat_s( RenameFrom, _countof(RenameFrom), "\" \"\0" );
strcat_s( RenameFrom, _countof(RenameFrom), RemoteRenameToNameWithFullPath );
strcat_s( RenameFrom, _countof(RenameFrom), "\"\0" );
quotelist = curl_slist_append( quotelist, RenameFrom );

MyCurlResult = curl_easy_perform(MyCurl);
```

Comment: That is strange, I tested both in absolute path and relative path and it worked fine. In the relative path case, the only POSTQUOTE command that I used was: `rename ./my_sftp_path/file_original.foo ./my_sftp_path/file_renamed.foo`