# Using Curllib to rename file after transfer (sftp)

Tags: libcurl, sftp

There is a similar question to this already but the [answer given does not solve my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4782872/libcurl-sftp-rename-file). Here is my code

.
.
    struct curl_slist *slist = NULL;

```
curl_easy_setopt( Curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);
curl_easy_setopt( Curl, CURLOPT_URL, "sftp://user:user@blah.blah.net:22/my_temp_file.txt");
curl_easy_setopt( Curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, my_read_func));
curl_easy_setopt( Curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, &my_read_data);

slist = curl_slist_append( slist, "RNFR my_temp_file.txt");
slist = curl_slist_append( slist, "RNTO my_file.txt");

curl_easy_setopt( Curl, CURLOPT_POSTQUOTE,  slist);

rc = curl_easy_perform(Curl);
```

.
.
.

When I run the above I get a CURLE_QUOTE_ERROR (the file transfer actually occurs but the rename doesn't happen). If I leave out the post quote option then all works (as before) with no error.

I've tried all the different formats for the from/to names but to no avail. Any ideas ?

Comment: I've already tried the 'rename' command. In fact I've tried numerous variations with no success (RNFR/RNTO, rename, full path, using ".\", "\", "./", "/", all with and without path etc. Very frustrating.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation says:

> The valid SFTP commands are: chgrp, chmod, chown, ln, mkdir, pwd,
>   rename, rm, rmdir, symlink (see curl (1))

So you'd use "rename" to rename a file.

The RNFR/RNTO you've used are FTP commands and despite the similarities in names, SFTP is very different compared to FTP.

Comment: Your code in the question is still wrong. You don't explain where in the directory tree the file you want to remain lies as compared to where you end up when the user "logs in" with SFTP. I think you simply use the wrong path.

Answer (score 1):

This SFTP version of the FTP cURL example works fine for me:

```
/***************************************************************************
 *                                  _   _ ____  _
 *  Project                     ___| | | |  _ \| |
 *                             / __| | | | |_) | |
 *                            | (__| |_| |  _ <| |___
 *                             \___|\___/|_| \_\_____|
 *
 * Copyright (C) 1998 - 2017, Daniel Stenberg, <daniel@haxx.se>, et al.
 *
 * This software is licensed as described in the file COPYING, which
 * you should have received as part of this distribution. The terms
 * are also available at https://curl.haxx.se/docs/copyright.html.
 *
 * You may opt to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute and/or sell
 * copies of the Software, and permit persons to whom the Software is
 * furnished to do so, under the terms of the COPYING file.
 *
 * This software is distributed on an "AS IS" basis, WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY
 * KIND, either express or implied.
 *
 ***************************************************************************/ 
/* <DESC>
 * Gets a file using an SFTP URL.
 * compile me:
 * gcc sftpup.c -lcurl  -o sftpup.exe
 * </DESC>
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <curl/curl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#ifdef WIN32
#include <io.h>
#else
#include <unistd.h>
#endif

/* <DESC>
 * Performs an FTP upload and renames the file just after a successful
 * transfer.
 * </DESC>
 */ 

#define LOCAL_FILE      "/tmp/uploadthis.txt"
#define UPLOAD_FILE_AS  "while-uploading.txt"
#define REMOTE_URL "sftp://sftpuser@123.1.1.1:/data/upload/" UPLOAD_FILE_AS
#define RENAME_FILE_TO  "renamed-and-fine.txt"

/* NOTE: if you want this example to work on Windows with libcurl as a
   DLL, you MUST also provide a read callback with CURLOPT_READFUNCTION.
   Failing to do so will give you a crash since a DLL may not use the
   variable's memory when passed in to it from an app like this. */ 
static size_t read_callback(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *stream)
{
  curl_off_t nread;
  /* in real-world cases, this would probably get this data differently
     as this fread() stuff is exactly what the library already would do
     by default internally */ 
  size_t retcode = fread(ptr, size, nmemb, stream);

  nread = (curl_off_t)retcode;

  fprintf(stderr, "*** We read %" CURL_FORMAT_CURL_OFF_T
          " bytes from file\n", nread);
  return retcode;
}

int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;
  FILE *hd_src;
  struct stat file_info;
  curl_off_t fsize;

  struct curl_slist *headerlist = NULL;
  static const char buf_1 [] = "rename /data/upload/" UPLOAD_FILE_AS " /data/upload/" RENAME_FILE_TO;

  /* get the file size of the local file */ 
  if(stat(LOCAL_FILE, &file_info)) {
    printf("Couldnt open '%s': %s\n", LOCAL_FILE, strerror(errno));
    return 1;
  }
  fsize = (curl_off_t)file_info.st_size;

  printf("Local file size: %" CURL_FORMAT_CURL_OFF_T " bytes.\n", fsize);

  /* get a FILE * of the same file */ 
  hd_src = fopen(LOCAL_FILE, "rb");

  /* In windows, this will init the winsock stuff */ 
  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

  /* get a curl handle */ 
  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    /* build a list of commands to pass to libcurl */ 
    headerlist = curl_slist_append(headerlist, buf_1);

    /* we want to use our own read function */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, read_callback);

    /* enable uploading */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1L);

    /* specify target */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, REMOTE_URL);

    /* pass in that last of FTP commands to run after the transfer */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTQUOTE, headerlist);

    /* now specify which file to upload */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, hd_src);

    /* Set the size of the file to upload (optional).  If you give a *_LARGE
       option you MUST make sure that the type of the passed-in argument is a
       curl_off_t. If you use CURLOPT_INFILESIZE (without _LARGE) you must
       make sure that to pass in a type 'long' argument. */ 
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE_LARGE,
                     (curl_off_t)fsize);

    /* Now run off and do what you've been told! */ 
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */ 
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    /* clean up the FTP commands list */ 
    curl_slist_free_all(headerlist);

    /* always cleanup */ 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  fclose(hd_src); /* close the local file */ 

  curl_global_cleanup();
  return 0;
}
```